# test client WCF throws error wjen invoked

Tags: wcf

I have WCF service which i want to test it,when the invoke box appears and i press invoke,it throws an error ,i have googled it but so far not able to run it,here the error i get:

The actual error message:

```
Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, restoring to default configuration, or refreshing the service.

    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
           at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
           at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
           at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
           at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

            Exception rethrown at [0]: 
               at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
               at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
               at ITurbineMonitorService.SetStatus(String turbineId, StatusChangeEventData statusChangeEvent)
               at TurbineMonitorServiceClient.SetStatus(String turbineId, StatusChangeEventData stat
```

here is my config which i run on localhost:

```
 <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service name="TurbineMonitor.TurbineMonitor">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="REST" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="TurbineMonitor.ITurbineMonitorService" />
    <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="TurbineMonitor.ITurbineMonitorService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Comment: You don't appear to have included the actual error message - just the stack trace?

Comment: @strickt01 the very first line is the actual error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the configuration file, we publish the service in two ways.one is restful style and the other is soap web service. One thing we should pay attention to is that WCF test client generally is used to test soap web service instead of restful style service, the latter is usually tested by Postman software. Therefore, I suggest you check whether you are testing the soap web service created by Basichttpbinding.
[image]
Besides, since the error details indicate that the service is inaccessible and offline, please check if IISExpress hosting the service properly. We are able to click the IISExpress icon at the bottom right corner and then check the running website.
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: thanks for the comment,i dont see my service in the IIS express,for that what should i do?

Comment: em, it seems that you have located the problem precisely. just restart VS and then open the svc file, Ctrl+F5 debug the service.

Comment: i righ clicked on the project selected start on IIs and now it appears but when i run still get error(the same)and on i browser i see HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory

Comment: the root directory of the project is not allowed to list by default. We should navigate the URL to http://localhost:xxxxx/service1.svc
Whereby we could check whether the service state works well.

Comment: yeah, and the port number.

Comment: i get the same error,im tryimg <endpoint address="http:/localhost:58221/service1.svc" behaviorConfiguration="REST" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="service1.ITurbine"/>

Comment: this service endpoint could not be tested in WCFtestclient.  Are you using Wcftestclient tool to test the service, or other ways?

Comment: I am using WCf test client ,which tool should i use?so sorry if my questions are stupid

Comment: don't mention it. try the below URL to generate the service endpoint in the tool. http:/localhost:58221/service1.svc/soap

Comment: You have created a service.
To test this service, you will need to create a client and use it to call the service. You can do this using the svcutil.exe tool from the command line with the following syntax:

svcutil.exe http://localhost:58221/service1.svc/mex

Comment: Good. we are almost there. in the Wcftestclient, try to directly invoke it by clicking the method.

Comment: you mean i should run the project again,when the WCF test client appears click on SetStatus()?because this was what i did before and got the error

Comment: i think i found it,i should run the command first on visual studio developer command prompt right?but since my drive C is restricted it cant create the file on it,access denied,any way to change the path?

Comment: now it gave me two files one is cs and the other one is output.xml